# API Manager 1.7.0: disable WSDL from being loaded into registry

Tags: wsdl, registry, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When you register a service in the WSO2 API Manager via the Web or through REST interface, you can add a WSDL to your service description. This WSDL is interpeted and loaded into the WSO2 API Manager registry. Is it possible to disable this? Only register the WSDL URL itself.

In our case we have the WSDL and XSD stored somewhere else. We do not want the API manager stores this defintion again in his own registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose to store WSDL is, if we store only the actual wsdl url and if we display that in store, user can directly invoke the backend service.(not via gateway)So, user will not use throttling there.

What we do is, when we store wsdl in APIManager, we change the service URLs in the original wsdl to point the gateway URL. So, when user creates request from the WSDL , always he will see the gateway URL only.